# Учебник по С

Tags: c++, c, книги

Здравствуйте. Что-то через гугл я выхожу на совсем старые учебники (позже нулевых). Кто какие учебники читал в свое время? Умею программировать на Java.
Может есть смысл вместо C взяться за C++? В этом случае обязательное условие - обратная совместимость, то есть чтобы зная C++, я также мог без труда разобраться в коде на C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Литература по программированию делится на два типа:

1. для тех кто умеет программировать
2. для тех кто только учиться.

У каждого типа есть свои плюсы.
Например литература для тех кто умеет программировать не содержит "воды", имеет маленький<br> размер и ее легко использовать как справочник. Хорошим примером служит "Керниган, Ричи. Язык C".
Самое лучшее пособие которое только может быть, но вам он расскажет как выделить память, а зачем это делать вам никто не будет пояснять.

Второй тип книг, отличается гораздо большим размером, что хорошо сказывается на понимании того что вы будете делать. На мой взгляд лучшим учебником будет 
"Объектно-ориентированное программирование в С++"  Р. Лафоре,
в России его выпускает издательство "Питер".

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, не все согласятся, но я считаю, что сначала стоит освоить Си, а затем браться за С++.
С++ - большой и сложный язык, чтобы сразу вникнуть во все его тонкости, даже после Java.
Поэтому лучше начать с Си.
Порекомендую книги:

- *Герберт Шилдт. Полный справочник по
     С*;
- *Стивен Прата. Язык программирования С++*.

Из русских авторов: *Подбельский В.В. "Программирование на языке Си"*.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую обратиться к книгам Герберта Шилдта из серии "Полное руководство по C/C++/C#", а также библии Си - "Керниган, Ричи. Язык C". 
А вообще если знаете Java, то и с С/C++ разобраться не составит труда. Надо лишь немного изменить концепцию мышления. 
P.S. Есть еще книга "Эволюция языка Си" (наверное так называется, точно не помню), того же автора-Кернигана.

Answer (score 2):

[[@kis](/users/13356/kis)](/users/13356/kis), Вы пишете, что умеете программировать на Java. Это означает, что Вы вообще умеете программировать.

Поэтому просто читаете K&R, а потом `man 3  intro, man stdlib.h, man stdio.h, man string.h, man ctype.h ...`, ну и раскручиваете SEE ALSO в них.

Конечно, за последние 30 лет кое-какие изменения (по сравнению с K&R) появились, но IMHO при известной базе они легко воспринимаются при чтении `/usr/include/*.h`.

В довесок стоит почитать
"Практика программирования" Автор: Брайан Керниган. Роб Пайк, в ней отличные примеры на разных языках, но в основном на Си.

Стоит ли изучать С++?

Почти наверняка Вам придется сталкиваться с чужими программами на нем. Поэтому изучать придется, но лучше уже освоив Си, поскольку несколькими сотнями страниц (как в K&R) тут не отделаешься.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю Java Си-подобный язык, а значит многое там должно быть общим. Нет только указателей. Так что изучить С++ будет несложно.

А из книг могу посоветовать:

Кент, Д. С++. Основы программирования.

Шилдт, Герберт, С++: базовый курс.

Дейтел, Дейтел, Как программировать на С.